# What does 'correlation' and 'de-correlation' mean in image-processing?

Tags: image-processing, statistics, dct

Here are some problems:

1. Does it mean these is some relationship among neighboring pixels?
2. I've read about DCT has a property of de-correlation, I have a doubt whether it means DCT neighbor coefficients have no relationship?
3. I've read some paper which says difference 2D-array(DCT coefficient subtracting by its neighbor) can weaken the relation of coefficients. How to understand this?

I would really appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: 1-yes there is similarity, 2-yes for typical images, 3-not clear.

Comment: Since you discuss correlation and not auto correlation, there is no information about neighborhood pixels relevant. DCT might introduce randomness so it could have impact on the correlation function - is it in the spatial domain or frequency domain? The third question is really not clear.

Comment: Image correlation shows the similarity between two images, while image decorrelation is an operation making two images dissimilar. If applied on a single image, correlation shows auto-correlation and decorrelation becomes image whitening.